# What is the difference between Ubuntu Server, Samba, and Apache Server?

Tags: server, terminology

I'm rather confused about the technical terminology of Ubuntu Server, Samba, and the Apache server.

Are they all separate things? What do each do? Are Samba and Apache Server included in the Ubuntu Server?

Answer (score 5):

- [Ubuntu Server](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/server) is an **operating system**, so you would install Samba or Apache **on top of** Ubuntu Server.
- [Apache](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_HTTP_Server) is a **webserver**, meaning it is used to host websites
- [Samba](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samba_(software)) is network **file-sharing** protocol.

Comment: In other words, they have no direct comparison at all.

Comment: So if i am already running Ubuntu OS(not Server). i have to install Ubuntu server as a dual boot or in VM . Or need suggestions on this can i install it inside ubuntu OS which i dont think so is possible.